# How to implement such tab layout with jquery tab plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using this [plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/),trying to implement this kind of layout:

```
<div id="aps">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs1-1">P1</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs1-1">
        <iframe src="publish.php"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

That is,for tabs to be added,I want the content to be:

```
<iframe src="publish.php"></iframe>
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an `<iframe>` you can load the page using AJAX:

```
$('#tabs1-1').load('publish.php');
```

Simple as that.